# input list of list in function argument in for loop python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using the below code to make a function that opens multiple files when the function is called

```
name = [['tina', 'vans', 'john', 'sam', 'victory'],['nanny', 'pink', 'sidewalk', 'paper', 'team'],['jimmy', 'rob', 'stack', 'layla', 'london']]


def get_name(in1, in2, in3, in4, in5): 
    open(f'{[in1]}.txt')
    open(f'{[in2]}.txt')
    open(f'{[in3]}.txt')
    open(f'{[in4]}.txt')
    open(f'{[in5]}.txt')
```

What i have problem now is that i want a for loop to insert in function arguments from the list of lists

first ['tina', 'vans', 'john', 'sam', 'victory']
second ['nanny', 'pink', 'sidewalk', 'paper', 'team']
and so on

Any info will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
names = [['tina', 'vans', 'john', 'sam', 'victory'],['nanny', 'pink', 'sidewalk', 'paper', 'team'],['jimmy', 'rob', 'stack', 'layla', 'london']]

def get_name(*names): 
    for name in names:
        open(f'{name}.txt')

for name in names:
    get_name(*name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method once

```py
name = [['tina', 'vans', 'john', 'sam', 'victory'],['nanny', 'pink', 'sidewalk', 'paper', 'team'],['jimmy', 'rob', 'stack', 'layla', 'london']]


def get_name(files): 
    open(f'{[files[0]]}.txt')
    open(f'{[files[1]]}.txt')
    open(f'{[files[2]]}.txt')
    open(f'{[files[3]]}.txt')
    open(f'{[files[4]]}.txt')

for i in name:

    get_name(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you just using for loop twice in your function.
There will no way to put entire list at the same time as parameter of function.

```
name = [['tina', 'vans', 'john', 'sam', 'victory'],['nanny', 'pink', 'sidewalk', 'paper', 'team'],['jimmy', 'rob', 'stack', 'layla', 'london']]

def get_name(name_lst): 
    for lst_ele in name_lst:
        for name_ele in lst_ele:
            open(f'{[name_ele]}.txt')
```